# QClipboard.mimedata() always has black background

Tags: python, pyside, qclipboard

I want to copy & paste by `QtGui.QClipboard` from `QApplication()`

`QtGui.QClipboard` has `mimedata()` method.

I can copy & paste from Web Site.

For example, I copied from here [Matahari Wikipedia](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matahari)

[image]

I pasted it on my sample text editer window.

At first, the pasted text was as follows:

[image]

and pressed Key_1 for saving its contents.

and reexcuted my code and pressed Key_2 for loading the contents.

so...,

[image]

The saved contents are always changed to black.

Why?

I checked the html by printing the mimedata.html().

As the result of it,

```
<!--StartFragment--><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: transparent; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Linux Libertine&quot;,&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;Times&quot;,serif; font-size: 28.8px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 37.44px; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">Matahari</span><!--EndFragment-->
```

You can see the color is (0,0,0). So this html is black.

So, I tried to do as follows:

```
clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()                         
html = clipboard.mimeData().html()
print(html)
html = html.replace("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);","color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
clipboard.mimeData().setHtml(html)
```

as the result of this execution:

```
<!--StartFragment--><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: transparent; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: &quot;Linux Libertine&quot;,&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;Times&quot;,serif; font-size: 28.8px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 37.44px; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">Matahari</span><!--EndFragment-->
```

I could make it. I could change the color (0,0.0) to (255,255,255)

And I resaved it and reloaded it, but the result was unchanged.

I want  to change the contents from black to white.

What should I do?

Here is the sample code for saving and reloading.

```
from PySide import QtGui

from PySide import QtCore
import sys
import os
class TextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TextEdit,self).__init__(parent=None)
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_1:
            self.save()
            return
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_2:
            self.load()
            return
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_V:
            self.copy_paste()
            return
        return QtGui.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self,event)
    def save(self):
        print(os.getcwd()+"copy_paste_test.dat")
        file = QtCore.QFile(os.getcwd()+"copy_paste_test.dat")
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadWrite)
        out = QtCore.QDataStream(file)
        out.writeQString(self.toHtml())
        file.close()
    def load(self):
        file = QtCore.QFile(os.getcwd()+"copy_paste_test.dat")
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        out = QtCore.QDataStream(file)
        self.insertHtml(out.readQString())
        file.close()
    def copy_paste(self):

        clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
        self.insertFromMimeData(clipboard.mimeData())      

def main():
    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    textedit = TextEdit()
    textedit.show()
    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I get the following:  https://imgur.com/a/26zAePl

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh...Does it depend on the Environment? In my occasion, my text is Always black.

Comment: I am using PySide 1.2.4 in Linux

Comment: @eyllanesc I am using PySide 1.2.4 in Windows10

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh, I copyied the title in the Wikipedia.Do you copy the link text? It seems you did so...it is blue text...

Comment: I copied the text you have placed on your question: `or example, I copied from here "Matahari"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check toHtml() in save() method.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head><body style=" font-family:'MS UI Gothic'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><span style=" font-family:'Linux Libertine,Georgia,Times,serif'; color:#000000; background-color:#000000;">Matahari</span></p></body></html>
```

You can see the background-color:#000000

So,you must change it to background-color:#FFFFFF

```
toHtml = self.toHtml()
toHtml = toHtml.replace("background-color:#000000;","background-color:#FFFFFF;")
out.writeQString(toHtml)
```

Comment: I have heard there is  png , transparent color has an influence on the background...which color I deignate as transparent color.